# React pass Object to Modal then set state of Object to that Object

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have some code where I set the state of an Object formEmpModal. I later pass the prop to the Modal, then in the modal I need to set the state of the object to this object. I can not get the syntax right. Below is an example of what its looking like. I shortened the code so its not exact. But i think its the part where I set the state in the constructor. I think since im trying to set it to the object i have the syntax wrong. Thank you for any help.

```
        const formEmpModal = {
          firstname: emp.firstname,
          lastname: emp.lastname,
        };
        this.setState({
          formEmpModal: formEmpModal 
});

console.log(formEmModal): //THIS DOES LOG THE OBJECT SO IT IS SETTING STATE CORRECTLY


<EmployeeDetailModal
formEmpModal = {this.state.formEmpModal}  // PASSING THE OBJECT TO THE MODAL
/>


export class EmployeeDetailModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formEmpModal: this.props.formEmpModal 
};};


console.log(this.props.formEmpModal.firstname) //THIS IS SAYING ITS UNDEFINED
```

Comment: in your constructor, try to remove ...prevstate. and keep only this.props.formEmpModal
you may also try to console.log(this.props) to make sure you're receiving the correct props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the state to the wrong component

```
<Modal
formEmpModal = {this.state.formEmpModal}  // PASSING THE OBJECT TO THE MODAL
/>
```

while at the other end recieving it from EmployeeDetailModal component

Correct way

```
<EmployeeDetailModal
formEmpModal = {this.state.formEmpModal}  // PASSING THE OBJECT TO THE MODAL
/>
```

Comment: hi Fahad, my apologies in my actual code i do have it correct. Also I do have this.props.formEmpModal  at the EmployeeDetailModal. This is still not working, I think its because in the Employee detail Modal when I state the object the syntax is incorrect even as export class EmployeeDetailModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formEmpModal: {this.props.formEmpModal }
};};